TypeError: basePath?.replace is not a function in SvelteKit with Auth.js during preview (works in dev mode)
Issue Summary:
While developing my SvelteKit application, I wasn't aware that @auth/sveltekit is currently in an experimental phase. I'm encountering an issue when running npm run preview for my application. The app works perfectly in development mode (npm run dev), but when I try to preview it with npm run preview, I get the following error:
TypeError: basePath?.replace is not a function
    at createActionURL (file:///path/to/project/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/utils/env.js:71:45)
    at auth (file:///path/to/project/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/hooks.server.js:83:22)
    at event.locals.auth (file:///path/to/project/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/hooks.server.js:140:35)
    at load (file:///path/to/project/.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_layout.server.js:4:33)
    at load_server_data (file:///path/to/project/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:519:42)
    at file:///path/to/project/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:1997:24

code:
// @ts-nocheck
import { SvelteKitAuth } from "@auth/sveltekit";
import Google from "@auth/core/providers/google";
import { AUTH_SECRET, GOOGLE_ID, GOOGLE_SECRET } from "$env/static/private";
import pool from "$lib/db";

export const {handle} = SvelteKitAuth({
    providers: [
        Google({
            clientId: GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: GOOGLE_SECRET
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({profile}) {
            const emailDomain = profile?.email?.split('@')[1];
            if(emailDomain !== "customDomain") {
                console.log('Unauthorised Domain', profile?.email)
                throw new AccessDenied('Unauthorised_Domain')
            }

            const [rows] = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [profile?.email])

       
            if(rows.length === 0){
                await pool.query('INSERT INTO users (name, email, picture) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [
                    profile?.name,
                    profile?.email,
                    profile?.picture
                ]);
            }
            return true;
        },
        async redirect({baseUrl }) {
            return baseUrl;  // Redirect to the home page after sign-in
        },
    secret: AUTH_SECRET
}})

Problem Details:

The error occurs in the createActionURL function of the auth.js module, specifically at the line where basePath.replace is called.
This issue only appears when using npm run preview, and it does not occur in development mode (npm run dev).
I'm using SvelteKit in combination with Auth.js and have set up Google authentication using @auth/sveltekit and @auth/core/providers/google.
The basePath seems to be undefined or incorrectly passed during the preview mode, but it works fine in development.

My Configuration:

SvelteKit Version: 2.0.0
@auth/core: 0.32.0
@auth/sveltekit: 1.2.0

Question:
How can I resolve the basePath?.replace is not a function error in preview mode? What is causing basePath to be undefined or incorrectly passed in the preview environment?
What I've Tried:

I’ve tried hardcoding the basePath as /, but that didn't resolve the issue.
I've checked the environment variables and ensured they are set correctly in the .env file.
The issue persists when using npm run preview, but works when running npm run dev.

